# how to select a statistical range in an excel

Tags: excel, statistics, iqr

I've got an array of a lot of numbers. These are daily readings over a 4 month period.
Each row represents a different device.
I need to calculate the trendline and ignore the outliers.
I tried calculating the IQR, then the range, and then filtering out the outliers that are not in the range.
the problem is that there are a lot of repetitive results so the q1 and the q3 could very easily be the same number.
is there a way to select the central 90% of results in a range?
lets say from:
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9] select [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,9,9,9,9]
to make life harder, I'd also like to be able to select the associated date with the day the measurement was taken. the dates are in a separate row.

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly but based on your example, if you exclude some numbers of your sample, then you are distorting results. I agree you need to manage outliers, but as I said, your example sample looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I also would advise caution when omitting outliers. Here is an article providing guidelines for when it's appropriate:
https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/remove-outliers/

That being said, the following formula will return a dynamic array that filters out the bottom 5% and the top 5%. It assumes your data range is A1:A20.

```
=FILTER($A$1:$A$20,(ROW($A$1:$A$20)>0.05*COUNT($A$1:$A$20))*ROW($A$1:$A$20)<0.95*COUNT($A$1:$A$20))
```